# passing object as a ref parameter to generic method

Tags: c#, object, generics, pass-by-reference, ref

I have created a generic method, and I want to pass an object by a reference to this method to populate few properties. It compiles, and runs without problems, but the object is not being populated.

my generic method

```
public static void SplitAddress<T>(ref T ob, string addressToSplit) where T : Address
    {
        //ptr : Postcode, Town, Region
        var ptr = addressToSplit.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        var pt = ptr[0].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

        if (ptr.Count == 2)
        {
            ob.Region = ptr[1];
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < pt.Count; x++)
        {
            switch (x)
            {
                case 0:
                    {
                        ob.PostCode = pt[x];
                        break;
                    }
                case 1:
                    {
                        ob.Town = pt[x];
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Object i want to pass

```
class Merchant : Address
{
    public int MeId { get; set; }
    public int HoId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string VatNr { get; set; }
    public string TRSshopId { get; set; }

}
```

Address class

```
abstract class Address
{
    public string PostCode;
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Adrress { get; set; }
}
```

method invocation

```
Methods.SplitAddress<Merchant>(ref me, row.Cells[i].Text);
```

I could create two overloaded methods, for two different object types, but they will repeat the same code, which I want to avoid. 
It look very odd, but for example "Postcode" is being populated, but when I hover the mouse on "ob", the property is still empty.

Comment: " I want to pass an object by a reference to this method to populate few properties" You don't need `ref` for that unless it's a `struct`

Comment: Why are you passing by reference at all? You never assign a value to `ob` within the method. We can't tell why the method isn't behaving as you expect it to given that we don't know what the data looks like, but I think you should read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: If you have the constraint of `T: Address` why even have a  generic method? Why not just have it take an `Address`?

Comment: @MattBurland: While it's using `ref`, that wouldn't work with a variable of type `Merchant`. But yes, removing `ref` would allow it to just take an `Address` reference by value...

Comment: Why are you redefining the properties in `Address` in the `Merchant` class? Your issue is probably due to hiding of the properties in the base class. It seems strange that `Merchant` inherits `Address` rather than containing an address however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

As @Lee astutely noticed, you are *hiding* the properties of `Address` in `Member`. Since your generic method is constrained to members of type `Address`, your code is actually changing the properties of the `Address` class that are hidden, not the properties of the `Merchant` class, so you are not seeing those changes if you have a variable of type `Merchant`.  You would see the values if you cast the `Member` to an `Address`.  Just remove those properties from `Merchant` and you should be fine.

p.s. `Member` *inheriting* form `Address` seems wrong - a member *has an* address, it *is not* an address.  a better design would be:

```
class Merchant
{
    public int MeId { get; set; }
    public int HoId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public string VatNr { get; set; }
    public string TRSshopId { get; set; }

}
```

**Original Answer**

> I want to pass an object by a reference to this method to populate few properties

Since `Address` is a class, you don't *need* to use `ref`.  A parameter of a reference types will contain a *reference* to the same object as the variable that's passed in, so you can change the values of the properties of that object and the calling method will see the changes.  The main thing `ref` lets you do is change the reference to a *different* object, which you aren't doing, so using `ref` won't change what you are trying to do.

I suggest you run it in the debugger to make sure your `if` blocks are getting executed the way you expect them to. (e.g. is `ptr.Count == 2` true? could it be greater then `2`?)

Also your entire `for` block can be reduced to:

```
if(pt.Count > 0)  ob.PostCode = pt[0];
if(pt.Count > 1)  ob.Town = pt[1];
```

Comment: You are right. the inheritance design was wrong. Thanks.  I know this is not the most simple way to do this, but i just needed to understand it before I quit it.

Comment: You mean when you have an Address property instead of inheriting?  You'd just access those fields through the property: `merchant.Address.Town`.  How disturbing is that?

Comment: I assume you meant to *not* have `Merchant` inherit from `Address` then? Because right now `Merchant` both inherits from `Address` and has an `Address` property.